# How to use Application.LoadFromSQLServer in Window authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to load ssispackages programatically.I am using Application.LoadFromSQLServer
but this method ask for some parameters like

```
public Package LoadFromSqlServer(
            string packagePath,
            string serverName,
            string serverUserName,
            string serverPassword,
            IDTSEvents events
        )
```

And i am using windows authentication.so how could i use this method in windows authentication mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Package Role properly when you import the package into SSIS, you can pass null as userid and password:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package pkg = default(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package);
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

pkg = app.LoadFromSqlServer("/Maintenance Plans/TestPackage", "DEEPTHOUGHT", null, null, null);
pkg.Execute();
```